# Rspec-Rails: How to create an active record collection with a faker factory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

I am trying to learn Rspec and I fail with testing a view that is expecting an Active Record collection (a simple index view).
I need a variable @books (which would usually contain Book.all), which shall be created with factory bot and faker.

This here doesn't seem to work - as this doesn't give back an Active Record collection, but rather a normal array of objects.

```
@books = Array.new(3) { create(:random_book) }
```

My Faker factory setup for :random_book:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :random_book, class: Book do
    title { Faker::Book.title }
    year { Random.rand(1920..2020) }
    rating { Random.rand(0..5) }
    condition { Random.rand(0..5) }
    association :book_format, factory: :not_defined
  end
end
```

Thanks for any help. I did read the "view spec" part of the RSpec doc but I don't get what they are doing there - the code that is there ALSO seems to create a simple array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are creating an array. If you want an ActiveRecord collection, then something like this might work:

```rb
3.times{ FactoryBot.create(:random_book) }
@books = Book.all
```

Comment: Thank you. That is interesting. it works but - actually Book.all is a pretty big collection of ALL books that were created in various tests... I have "before(:all)" blocks at the beginning of all of my tests, so it looks like the books remain there from previous tests? How to ensure that this does not happen (ie test data from other specs are disposed before continuing)?

Comment: Cleaning the db between tests is essential., typically the "database_cleaner" gem is used. https://rubygems.org/gems/database_cleaner/versions/1.5.3

Comment: Thanks. That fixed a bunch of other issues as well :)